# loacal database in windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I used the step-by-step building application from the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876(v=vs.92).aspx 
but the .sdf file won't create! I can insert data to DB but in second run it will clear and DB works just like buffer! why .sdf file won't create in project folder?
I use 7.1 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB is getting created in the isoloatedstorage. You can dump that db file to your local mashine using the tool microsoft has provided. Then you have to add that db file to your project or solution folder.

Comment: it means that, it won't build by the db.CreateDatabase(); statement? I must create the file manually and add it to the project folder?

Comment: db file will be created by the app. You need to manually copy it after the application is closed. Emulator should not be closed.

Comment: so, where is the file? from where i must copy it to application directory?

Comment: it wasn't here C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE

Comment: The tool resides in below location  
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool

This is a command line tool. You will get more information from MSDN regarding how to use this tool.